# Using a fixed attribute for multiple objects

Tags: python, class

Sorry for the confusing title because I really don't know how to describe this question.
I will try to use an example to explain.

Say I want to write a class

```
class Line:
    def __init__(self, x1, y1, x2, x3):
        self.start = (x1, y1)
        self.end = (x2, y2)
    def length(self, metric):
        # return the length of this line using the input metric
```

Here `metric` is a metric on the plane (it might be a function, or a table etc, not important here)

Now I want to do something like

```
def findLine(metric):
    l1 = Line(0,0,1,1)
    l2 = Line(0,0,2,2)
    # just an example, I may need to create a lot of lines then compare their length
    if l1.length(metric)>l2.length(metric):
        return l1
```

I am looking for a way that somehow setting a default value for `metric` for all the lines used in `findLine`

so I can simply call `l1.length()>l2.length()` in `findLine`.

Also, the data `metric` might be stored in a large data frame. I think it might be not good to store them in each line.

Sorry for the confusing. I am just trying to find a way to simplify my code.

---

I should add that in my code, there are 5 or 6 these kind of parameters not just one.

That's the reason I want to find a way to not writing all parameters every time.

Thanks!

Comment: You can pass ‘metric’ into each Line you create.

Comment: The question is confusing as well as the title. Are you looking for a default attribute value, e.g. `def length(self, metric='xxx'):`?

Comment: I have edited the question, hope it is clearer. Thank you.

Comment: You say that: `data metric might be stored in a large data frame`, but if *every* `Line` has its own reference to it, you only increase `Line` by an additional reference, and not by the size of the `large data frame`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a class attribute:

```
class Line:
    metric = (1,2)

    def __init__(self, x1, y1, x2, y2):
        self.start = (x1, y1)
        self.end = (x2, y2)

    def length(self):

        return Line.metric+self.start
# return the length of this line using the input metric

l = Line(1,2,3,4)
m = Line(4,5,6,7)

print(l.metric)
print(m.metric)
print(l.length())
print(m.length())
```

This belongs to the class and not the instance. Any instance will have the same value for `metric`. You can access the value for `metric` within the instance by calling the original `Line` class as opposed to `self`.

If you want `metric` to occur only in some instances but not others, you had better add it as an instance attribute:

```
class Line:
    def __init__(self, x1, y1, x2, y2, metric=None):
        self.start = (x1, y1)
        self.end = (x2, y2)
        self.metric = metric

    def length(self):
        if self.metric is not None:
            return self.metric + self.start
        else:
            return 'Line has no metric'
    # return the length of this line using the input metric


metric1 = (1,2)
metric2 = (2,3)
l = Line(1, 2, 3, 4, metric=metric1)
m = Line(4, 5, 6, 7, metric=metric2)
n = Line(8, 9, 10, 11)

print(l.metric)
print(m.metric)
print(l.length())
print(m.length())
print(n.length())
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you think it is possible to do this without storing the metric into every lines?

Comment: Yes, but then the lines which don't have a `metric` would not be able to use the `length` method. Are you OK with that?

Comment: This is just what @user32882 has done: There is *one* metric, but *every* instance can see that one metric.

Comment: I thought by doing this, it would copy a new metric and store it into each line. But it actually will only reference to the origin metric, is the right? Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you pass `metric` into your `__init__` method then? That will make it an instance attribute. I'll edit my answer to show what I mean

Comment: I didn't do that because I thought it would copy a new `metric` and store it into a new line every time I create a new line. But if it's simply referencing the original `metric` then I am good with that. Thanks.

Comment: It won't if you make it optional. See the edit to my original answer. You can have different lines have different metrics, or no metric at all... but then it has to be part of the instance....